# Mysqli Connect Database Error When Connetion Unstable When Database Is Loaded Twice Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have unsolved case when use $this->load->database("Db",TRUE); Please note that iam using codeigniter in here.

**Here is the case :**

I make a controller named **"cdata"** this controller handle and save a device log from absence machine. I am using **ADMS type absence machine.**

**How ADMS Machine work ?**

When an employee do a finger scan, the absence machine will send a **Http** **Request** named **"cdata"**. This **"cdata"** contain a log from absence in raw data so i will use handle raw data in codeigniter to capture a log absence like time, user id, state checkin or check out. So when ADMS machine send a request **"cdata"** i will have a controller named "cdata" to handle it.

**The script "cdata" is like below :**

```
class cdata extends CI_Controller {
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

function index(){
    $result = "NONE";
    $table = $this->input->get('table');
    $sn = $this->input->get('SN');
    $op = $this->input->get('options');
    if ($table == "ATTLOG"){
        $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
        log_message('error', $data);
        echo "OK:1
              POST from: ".$sn."";
        $result = "OK:1";

        $arraydata = explode(chr(9),trim($data));

        if (count($arraydata) > 0) {
            $userid = $arraydata[0];
            $date = $arraydata[1];
            $state = $arraydata[2];
            $verification = $arraydata[3];
            $workcode = $arraydata[5];
            $reserved = $arraydata[6];

            $insertdata = array("sn_device"=>$sn,
                                "user_id"=>$userid,
                                "date_time"=>$date,
                                "state"=>$state,
                                "verification"=>$verification,
                                "work_code"=>$workcode,
                                "reserved"=>$reserved,
                                "create_date"=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                                "ip_address"=>$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);

            $result = $this->db->insert("tbl_log",$insertdata);

        }
        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->db->from('tbl_forward');
        $this->db->where(array('sn_device = ' => $this->db->escape_str($sn)));
        $row = $this->db->get()->result();

        foreach ($row as $rows) {
            $db = array(
            'dsn'   => '',
            'hostname' => $rows->hostname,
            'port'     => $rows->port,
            'username' => $rows->username,
            'password' => $rows->password,
            'database' => $rows->database_name,
            'dbdriver' => $rows->db_type,
            'dbprefix' => '',
            'pconnect' => FALSE,
            'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
            'cache_on' => FALSE,
            'cachedir' => '',
            'char_set' => 'utf8',
            'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
            'swap_pre' => '',
            'encrypt' => FALSE,
            'compress' => FALSE,
            'stricton' => FALSE,
            'failover' => array(),
            'save_queries' => TRUE);


            $this->sqldb = $this->load->database($db, TRUE);

            if ($rows->db_type == "sqlsrv") {
                $LogNo = $this->models_database->GenerateNo ('DeviceLogs','LogNo');
            }

            if(count($arraydata) > 0) {
                $userid = $arraydata[0];
                $date = $arraydata[1];
                $state = $arraydata[2];
                $verification = $arraydata[3];
                $workcode = $arraydata[5];
                $reserved = $arraydata[6];

                if ($rows->db_type == "mysqli") {
                    $insertdata = array("DeviceNo" => $rows->receiver_id,
                                        "UserID" => $userid,
                                        "LogDate" => $date,
                                        "EditedUserID" => $userid,
                                        "EditedDeviceNo" => $rows->receiver_id,
                                        "EditedLogDate" => $date,
                                        "CreatedBy" => "ADMS",
                                        "CreatedOn" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                                        "LogTypeNo" => $state,
                                        "EditedLogTypeNo" => $state,
                                        "IsEdit" => True,
                                        "IsImport" => 1,
                                        "IsAutoCreated" => 1,                                           
                                        "LogSourceNo" => 1,
                                        "IsDefault" => NULL,
                                        "Remarks" => "None",
                                        "UpdateOn" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                                        "UpdateBy" => "ADMS",
                                        "FileID" => 1,
                                        "TempID" => 1,
                                        "VerifyMethodNo" => 0,
                                        "BranchNo" => NULL,
                                        "FileName" => NULL,
                                        "CardNo" => NULL);

                    $result = $this->sqldb->insert("DeviceLogs",$insertdata);

                } else if ($rows->db_type == "sqlsrv") {
                    $insertdata = array("LogNo"=>$LogNo, 
                                        "DeviceNo" => $rows->receiver_id,
                                        "UserID" => $userid,
                                        "LogDate" => $date,
                                        "EditedUserID" => $userid,
                                        "EditedDeviceNo" => $rows->receiver_id,
                                        "EditedLogDate" => $date,
                                        "CreatedBy" => "ADMS",
                                        "CreatedOn" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                                        "LogTypeNo" => $state,
                                        "EditedLogTypeNo" => $state,
                                        "IsEdit" => True,
                                        "LogSourceNo" => 1,
                                        "IsDefault" => 1,
                                        "Remarks" => "None",
                                        "UpdateOn" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                                        "UpdateBy" => "ADMS",
                                        "CardNo" => NULL);

                    $result = $this->sqldb->insert("DeviceLogs",$insertdata);
                }                   
            }                           
        }   
        $this->db->trans_complete();
    } 
}
```

}

That script is use to save an absence log to a **local database** and then forward a absence log to **another database** where it is depend on the hostname, username, password and database name.

**The problem is here :**

**When the connection is stable or is good**. It doesn't matter how fast i do a finger scan the controller will do as it and the data saved to local and saved to another database without an error.

**But when i make the connection unstable or bad connection** (this i make a high packet in this two ip, one from machine and one the computer) we can call the connection LAGGER, when i repeatly do a finger scan, i got **an error** when calling **cdata** twice in this line :

> ***$this->sqldb = $this->load->database($db, TRUE);***

**The error is :**

> Message:  mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond.\r\n

***It is look like when controller cdata is called i cannot call load database twice when in unstable connection.***

**What should i do ? What is wrong in here ?**

From my opinion maybe this first **"cdata"** load database ***$this->sqldb = $this->load->database($db, TRUE);*** is still loading and then another called  **"cdata"** load database ***$this->sqldb = $this->load->database($db, TRUE);*** is called too.

Thank You

Dennis Liu

Comment: @DeadManAlive no. it just a dummy. I just make it clear for add a dummy password.

Comment: @DeadManAlive So i have a table named tbl_forward that list a database config. So i will get all tbl_forward data which include a hostname, user, password, port and database name I will use this to forward a log absence to the another database list in tbl_forward using looping foreach

Comment: @DeadManAlive the script above work when connection in stable. But when connection unstable look like i cannot call load database twice.

Comment: @DeadManAlive $rows->database_name = absence_db

Comment: @DeadManAlive only one value if in tbl_forward there is only one data. If there are two data in tbl_forward. $rows->database_name = absence_db then looping again $rows->database_name = absence_db2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164945/discussion-between-dennis-liu-and-dead-man-alive).